# disable react extra div wrapper

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, less

Is it possible to disable react disable react extra div wrapper?
I'm using ES2015.

The wrapper is making two of my style  not centering my component in C#.

```
#First div
.default-content {
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding: 16px 16px 16px 16px;
}

#second div
.full-width {
    width:100%;
}
```

The code looks like this when its rendered.:

```
    <react-container params="component: MontelUI.React.CompactStory, args: { 
     newsId: 955888, userId: 1003465, bookmarkMainProp: false  }">
       <div>
           <div>hei</div>
       </div>
    </react-container>
```

My render function looks like this:

```
render() {

    return (
        <div>hei</div>
    )
```

The component is called through custom-tag.

Comment: What is this "extra div wrapper"?  I'm not familiar with such a thing in React.

Comment: Can u show your render functions where the extra `div` appears?

Answer (score 0):

There is an option for this situation. You are not clear about what you meant but as I understood, you have and component which has `div` and to be able to render multiple components you need to wrap with `div`. But instead of this you can use `Fragments`! Try to analyze this link and wrap your component with `Fragment` not `div`!

[Fragments in React](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html)

Like this ->

```
render() {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <ChildA />
      <ChildB />
      <ChildC />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```